# How to get href using innertext and regex

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to get Href from the `<a>` tag.

how to get href link using selectors, I have tried like below but it didn't work.

expected to get "www.test.com/all_reviews"

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a[href =*'all_reviews'*]")
console.log(a)
```

```html
<a href="www.test.com/all_reviews">All Reviews</a>
<a href="www.test.com/all_reviews/altered">All Reviews</a>
```

Comment: As you can see the selector is invalid

Comment: `("a[href*='all_reviews']")` - if there is only one, use querySelector instead of querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

To access the `href` you should use `getAttribute` of the selected element

```js
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="all_reviews"]');
let link = null;
Array.from(anchors).forEach(element => {
    let pattern = /all_reviews$/;
    let url = element.getAttribute('href');
    if(pattern.test(url)) {
      link = url;
    }
});

console.log(link);
```

```html
<a href="www.test.com/all_reviews">All Reviews</a>
<a href="www.test.com/all_reviews/altered">All Reviews</a>
```

You can use a Regular expression which check if the link and with `all_reviews` as the second link `all_reviews` is not at the end of the URL.

Comment: thank you. got one more problem i just updated my question please check it. if having multiple <a>.

Comment: I made few changes you can check the new code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery :contains() selector like this:

```
 $("a:contains(All Reviews)")
```

See a code example and read more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/